# Content subscriptions/notifications from multiple terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, notifications

I have a clothing site where multiple taxonomy vocabularies are used for content. For example, there are "Boys" and "Girls" terms, and clothing size terms such as "2" "4" "6" etc., as well as "Seasons" and "Sport" vocabularies.

A user only wants to be alerted when "Boys" "4" "Basketball" new content is posted.

I am aware that modules such as [Notifications](https://drupal.org/project/notifications), [Subscriptions](https://drupal.org/project/subscriptions), [Simplenews](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews), etc. exist -- but these only allow for new content notifications based on a single taxonomy term.

Could this be done with [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) (e.g. content type that contains each users' subscribed terms)? Or some other way, perhaps using [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag)?

Comment: You mean it has to have ALL the selected terms as opposed to having ANY of them?

Comment: That's correct. All must match.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use case for my site.  What I do is utilize views loops.  I create a view rule that accepts multiple taxonomy terms (I use AND rather than OR.  I think you would too).  Any user who has all the items in their profile is then sent a PM when on Create New Content.  It's not terribly elegant but it works.  I think it may be a bit too restrictive.  But Them's the breaks.

Comment: I think I get it. You've made it a field on the user's profile. Short of a custom module, this is a good solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use my module for this [Total Subscription](https://drupal.org/project/total_subscription).

> Total Subscription provides functionality which would allow the user to subscribe to node pages, taxonomy terms, etc. The main feature which distinguishes it from other subscription modules is that it allows subscription for Anonymous along with Authenticated users.